# Styling for tag specific badges is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here's a screenshot of my badge list.  The blank looking spot is the badge for the civilization 5 tag.

[image]

Comment: What browser/OS?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a hard refresh? Ctrl+F5. I recently updated the image sprite for the badge-tags.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to fix it, I'm now getting the blue that is shown in @Willful's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome/Win 7, I get this, which I'm not sure this is right either...

What browser are you using?

[image]

*(Not a comment so I could add the image)*

Comment: Color is supposed to be different: tag badges use a different background color in order to distinguish them from the other badges. At least, I've seen that on Meta Stack Overflow. Though I didn't expect blue (which it is for me, IE8 on XP).

Comment: Im getting blue on my droidx